# MathJax JS API: How to send a var with text in it and get html out of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, var, mathjax

From some external source (flash app for example) I get text (which is mix of simple html, wiki markdown and TeX/LaTeX). Currently I have: (I use jQuery)

```
      function render(text)
     {
         $("#wikiContent").html(text);
         MathJax.Hub.Typeset()
         $("#wikiContent").html(Markdown_Showdown_Converter.makeHtml( $("#wikiContent").html()));
     }
```

And that results in next problem - any complex math like [such](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76018/does-b-1z-1-m-1-equiv-b-2-pmod-m-2-mean-that-z-1-b-2-bmod-m-2-b-1):

```
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
B_1 + z_1 M_1 &\equiv& B_2 \pmod {M_2}
\\ B_1 + z_1 M_1 + z_2 M_1M_2 &\equiv& B_3 \pmod {M_3}
\\ &\cdots&
\\ B_1 + z_1M_1 + z_2 M_1M_2 + \cdots + z_{k-1}M_1 M_2 \cdots M_{k-1} &\equiv& B_k \pmod{M_k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
```

gets broken=(

So I wonder how to put some var into MathJax and get html out of it?

Answer (score 2):

You should not call `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` directly, but rather use the `MathJax.Hub.Queue()` to queue the typesetting.  Since the typesetting operates asynchronously, you would need to queue the code that looks up the resulting HTML as well.  Something like

```
function render(text)
{
  $("#wikiContent").html(text);
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(
    ["Typeset",MathJax.Hub],
    function () {
      $("#wikiContent").html(Markdown_Showdown_Converter.makeHtml($("#wikiContent").html()));
    }
  );
}
```

See the MathJax documentation about [modifying math on the page](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/typeset.html) for more details.

Note, however, that the HTML that you get is not universal (that is, it depends on the browser you are using, the OS, the fonts you have installed, the CSS on the page where MathJax runs, and a variety of other factors, so you will not be able to copy and paste the HTML into another page and expect consistent results.